# Linker errors on c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the implementation of the shortest path problem (code: http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/code/ch9-1.1.tar.gz). However, I am getting errors:

```
le@le-Extensa-4630:~/Desktop/code/ch9-1.1$ make
cd ./gens;    make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/le/Desktop/code/ch9-1.1/gens'
cd ./grid;    make
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/le/Desktop/code/ch9-1.1/gens/grid'
gcc -O6 -DNDEBUG -DPERMUTE_NODES  -I ../../lib -I ../../lib/ll-core/include -o spgrid.exe spgrid.c -lm         -I../../lib/ ../../lib/ll-core/src/*.c
../../lib/ll-core/src/LConnectivity.c: In function ‘_visitaDSFRicorsiva’:
../../lib/ll-core/src/LConnectivity.c:114:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ui4’ [-Wformat]
../../lib/ll-core/src/LFile_posix.c: In function ‘LFile_GetTempName’:
../../lib/ll-core/src/LFile_posix.c:171:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘tmpnam’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
../../lib/ll-core/src/LSystem.c: In function ‘LSystem_GetString’:
../../lib/ll-core/src/LSystem.c:47:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
/tmp/ccGnQJPS.o: In function `LArray_ResizeBy':
LArray.c:(.text+0x354): undefined reference to `log'
LArray.c:(.text+0x38e): undefined reference to `pow'
LArray.c:(.text+0x402): undefined reference to `log'
LArray.c:(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `pow'
/tmp/ccVDr0iU.o: In function `LGraphUtil_RandomUNM':
LGraphUtil.c:(.text+0x988): undefined reference to `sqrt'
LGraphUtil.c:(.text+0x997): undefined reference to `sqrt'
LGraphUtil.c:(.text+0x9a6): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [spgrid.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/le/Desktop/code/ch9-1.1/gens/grid'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/le/Desktop/code/ch9-1.1/gens'
make: *** [code] Error 2
```

Comment: You're missing the includes for a math library somewhere.  `log` `pow` and `sqrt` can't be found.  Find the file those functions are defined in, and make sure they're in the right directory, or that you include that directory.

Comment: These are linker errors with math lib. Try adding "-lm" to the command line of the final gcc command.

Comment: @JoshG79 It's already in the command line.

Comment: @RyanWH No, this has nothing to do with header files.

Comment: You tagged this question with C++, but you compile with `gcc` instead of `g++`. Any reason?

Comment: Wow! `-O6`, that must be fast! Did you know that modern GCC versions have the `-Ofast` option.

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't say it had to do with header files.  `undefined reference to 'log'` means that the linker can't find the file where `log` is defined.

Comment: @RyanWH I know what it means. But in the comment aboe, you wrote "You're missing the **includes** for a math library somewhere" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @H2CO3 When I said include, I didn't mean `#include`.  I'm talking about the command used to compile the code.  I'm not familiar with GCC options, but there needs to be an option that points to a library or directory with a library with those files in it.  From what others are saying, I'm guessing that's `-lm`.

Comment: @RyanWH check the makefiles or read my answer, the error is probably somewhere else and the linker could probably never solve this no matter what flags or includes you are using.

Comment: Put the -lm at the end of the command line. Depending of the gcc/binutils the order matters.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Makefile to change the -lm position.
Put the -lm at the end of the command line because depending of the gcc/binutils the order matters*.

[1] Libraries may need to appear after the objects that need them.

Comment: Indeed, the command line ends with a wildcard compiling a bunch of other *.c files.

Comment: Thank you.Please say more details. There is not only one Makefile

Comment: Check how the makefile (probably in /gen/grid) construct the line for the gcc. At one part it probably put all together (gcc {FLAGS} {LIBS} {FILES}) before calling it. Find where it does and change the order (putting the libs in the end) to see if it works.

Comment: I changed the order. But it did not work, I get the same errors.